# Why I can't acces this property in my class

Tags: javascript, properties, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to use this class to play and pause an interval timer but I am having problems with pause(). I don't know why I can't acces the timerId property from pause().

this.timerId return `null` in pause() . What am I doing wrong?

```
class IntervalTimer {
  callbackStartTime;
  remaining = 0;
  paused = false;
  timerId = null;
  _callback;
  _delay;

  constructor(callback, delay) {
    this._callback = callback;
    this._delay = delay;
  }

  pause() {
    console.log("this.timerId", this.timerId); //return null
    if (!this.paused) {
      this.clear();
      this.remaining = new Date().getTime() - this.callbackStartTime;
      this.paused = true;
    }
  }

  resume() {
    if (this.paused) {
      if (this.remaining) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.run();
          this.paused = false;
          this.start();
        }, this.remaining);
      } else {
        this.paused = false;
        this.start();
      }
    }
  }

  clear() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
  }

  start() {
    console.log("this.timerId", this.timerId); // return timerId correctly
    this.clear();
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
      this.run();
    }, this._delay);
  }

  run() {
    this.callbackStartTime = new Date().getTime();
    this._callback();
  }
}

export default IntervalTimer;
```

Here my code where I use the class

```
 const interval = new IntervalTimer(() => {
    // Coger un número aleatorio de los que quedan y borrarlo
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numbersLeft.length);
    let randomNumber = numbersLeft[randomIndex];
    if (randomIndex > -1) numbersLeft.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    // Pasarle el número cogido al estado
    const tempNList = numberList;
    if (lastNumber) numberList.push(lastNumber);

    setNumberList(tempNList);
    setNumber(randomNumber);

    lastNumber = randomNumber;
  }, BALLTIME);

  const startGame = () => {
    interval.start();
  };

  const pauseGame = () => {
    interval.pause();
  };
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that calls, or otherwise uses, the `pause` method. Presumably its getting called in a way that "loses" its `this` context, but since you don't show us how we can't say for sure. I guess putting `this.pause = this.pause.bind(this)` in the constructor would fix it but that might be considered overkill.

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question

Comment: thanks. I'm puzzled because calling the method this way should work. I don't see how `this.timerId` could be undefined unless you're calling `pauseGame` before `startGame` (which you don't show us but I am choosing to assume is not the case!)

Comment: it would be interesting to log what `this` is - to see whether its your `IntervalTimer` instance with an `undefined` `timerId`, or whether it's the `window` object or something else unexpected.

Comment: Can’t reproduce this issue but you forgot to set `this.paused` to `false` in `start`. `if(!this.paused)` will never run in `paused` again if you only use `start` and `paused`.

Comment: if I log `this` after click on pause() this is what I get: `IntervalTimer {remaining: 0, paused: false, timerId: null, _delay: 1000, _callback: ƒ}
paused
: 
true
remaining
: 
NaN
timerId
: 
null
_callback
: 
() => {…}
_delay
: 
1000`

Comment: @dandomin So is `this.timerId` `null` or is it `undefined`? Which one is it? It can’t be `undefined`. If it’s `null`, that’s not a bug.

Comment: Sorry, it is null! not undefined. But why??

Comment: @dandomin Because that’s the initial value. If you call `start` before `pause`, then `pause` will never report `this.timerId` as `null`. However, if you call `pause` first, why would you ever expect something other than `null` in the first call? Where would `this.timerId` get defined? _`start`_ reports `this.timerId` as `null`, which is _correct_.

Comment: But the problem is that I call `start` and I get the timerId correctly, but then I call `pause` and the interval doesn't pause because it can't pass the itemId to the `clearInterval()`. It's calling `clearInterval(null)` instead of `clearInterval(timerId)`

Comment: @dandomin Again, this is not reproducible, and again, you don’t set `this.paused` to `false` in `start`. That’s the main issue, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I solved it this way. I made `start()` return the `this.timerId` and then I can call `pause(timerId)` so basically I am taking the `this.timerId` outside the class to use it via parameter. Now it's working, but honestly I don't know why it wasn't working before. Thanks anyway for spending time on it!

```
class IntervalTimer {
  callbackStartTime;
  remaining = 0;
  paused = false;
  timerId = null;
  _callback;
  _delay;

  constructor(callback, delay) {
    this._callback = callback;
    this._delay = delay;
  }

  pause(timerIDfromOutside) { //using the returned this.timerID in start()
    if (!this.paused) {
      this.clear(timerIDfromOutside);
      this.remaining = new Date().getTime() - this.callbackStartTime;
      this.paused = true;
    }
  }

  resume() {
    if (this.paused) {
      if (this.remaining) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.run();
          this.paused = false;
          this.start();
        }, this.remaining);
      } else {
        this.paused = false;
        this.start();
      }
    }
  }

  clear(timerIDfromOutside) {
    clearInterval(timerIDfromOutside); 
  }

  start() {
    this.paused = false
    this.clear();
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
      this.run();
    }, this._delay);
    return this.timerId //return this.timerId so I can pass it as a parameter in 
    // pause()
  }

  run() {
    this.callbackStartTime = new Date().getTime();
    this._callback();
  }
}
```